# Returning a list of the values from the binary tree

Tags: python, tree, python-3.x, depth-first-search

I want to return a list of the values from the binary tree.  Is there a shorter and more efficient way to write the method for numbers?

```
class BTNode(object):
    """A node in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        """(BTNode, object, BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store item and have children left and right,
        as well as depth 0.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.depth = 0  # the depth of this node in a tree

    def number(self: 'BTNode') -> list:
        lst = []

        if self.right is None and self.left is None:
            lst.append(self.item)
        else:
            lst.append(self.item)
        if self.left:
            left = self.left.number()
            lst.extend(left)
        if self.right:
            right = self.right.number()
            lst.extend(right)
        return lst
```

Comment: I think `number` would be better named `enumerate`.

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no docstring for the `number` method.
2. There are no test cases. This kind of code would be an ideal opportunity to write some [doctests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).
3. The `depth` property is always 0. This seems useless.
4. The method name `number` is misleading. (It does not return a number.) I would call it something like `flattened_pre_order` because it *flattens* the tree into a list using [*pre-order traversal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).
5. The variable name `lst` is misspelt. Better to call it something like `result`.
6. This code:

   ```
   if self.right is None and self.left is None:
       lst.append(self.item)
   else:
       lst.append(self.item)
   ```

   can be replaced with:

   ```
   lst.append(self.item)
   ```

   since it doesn't matter whether the condition is true or false.
7. There's quite a lot of copying going on in the traversal of the tree: each time you call `a.extend(b)`, Python has to copy out the list `b`. This copying causes the traversal of a tree with *n* nodes to take O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time instead of O(*n*). See below for a way to avoid this copying.
8. You use recursion to visit the child nodes, which means that traversing a very deep tree will exceed Python's maximum recursion depth:

   ```
   >>> n = None
   >>> for i in range(1000): n = BTNode(i, n)
   ... 
   >>> n.number()
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "cr33662.py", line 22, in number
       left = self.left.number()
     [... many lines omitted ...]
   RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
   ```

   The way to avoid this is to maintain your own stack, like this:

   ```
   def flattened_pre_order(self: 'BTNode') -> list:
       """Return a list of items in the tree rooted at this node, using
       pre-order traversal.

           >>> tree = BTNode(1, BTNode(2, None, BTNode(3)), BTNode(4))
           >>> tree.flattened_pre_order()
           [1, 2, 3, 4]
           >>> node = BTNode(9999)
           >>> for i in range(9998, -1, -1): node = BTNode(i, node)
           >>> node.flattened_pre_order() == list(range(10000))
           True

       """
       result = []
       stack = [self]
       node = None
       while stack:
           if node is None:
               node = stack.pop()
           if node is not None:
               result.append(node.item)
               stack.append(node.right)
               node = node.left
       return result
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building up a list and returning it, consider implementing a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types) instead.  Then you could "yield" each `self.item`.  If the result is going to be processed one at a time and the result is a very long list you save the expense of building up that long list.

```
def __iter__(self):
    ''' Pre-order iterator '''
    yield self.item
    if self.left:
        for item in self.left:
            yield item
    if self.right:
        for item in self.right:
            yield item
```

Furthermore, you can easily reimplement the original function by taking advantage of the generator:

```
def number(self: 'BTNode') -> list:
    ''' Pre-order traversal '''
    return list(self)
```